# Dynamic attributes using bootstrap/css design. We are not able to perform action using selenium

Tags: css, selenium

[image]

As per the above code, I have tried to locate and perform action on elements in Selenium.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
```

Putting Control to Elements

```
          WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='static dynamic-children']/a[@href='/activa/gentex/ee/#']/span[@class='additional-background']"));
          action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
          WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
      // wait for the edit employee information to appear
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By
        .xpath("//a[contains(@class,'selected')]/span[@class='additional-background']/span[@class='menu-item-text']")));
//       action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='zz1_TopNavigationMenuV4']/div/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li[2]/a/span/span"))).build().perform();
//        action.click(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='zz1_TopNavigationMenuV4']/div/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li[2]/a/span/span"))).perform();
```

Moving control to Child menu item to click on it.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'selected')]/span[@class='additional-background']/span[@class='menu-item-text']")).click();
```

Comment: can you please share website URL to check it? Also you want to click on submenu?

Comment: Sorry this is intranet access URL.
I can share design and screenshot of this

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hvKgM.jpg
check this URL to view web page

Comment: you want to select sub menu , right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have incorrect xpath , Please check correct code below :

```
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebElement Mainmenu= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='zz1_TopNavigationMenuV4']/div/ul/li/ul/li[1]"));
            action.moveToElement(Mainmenu).build().perform();

            WebElement submenu1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='zz1_TopNavigationMenuV4']/div/ul/li/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span/span"));


            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='zz1_TopNavigationMenuV4']/div/ul/li/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span/span")));

            submenu1.click();
```

I am hovering mouse on main menu : My Benefit Resources and then clicking on child menu : Enrollment. Above code should work fine for you.

Comment: no its not working
it is able to to verify the presence of element
after that its not able to click on the element

Comment: Unable to locate element... :(

Answer (score 0):

For reading the tags  try this :

```
<span>xyz</span>
```

You can try this:
re-frame the xpath as

```
//span[contains(.,'xyz')]
```

It should help.

Comment: I have tried with this also. Encountered same issue. it is able to to identify but not able to perform click operation on element.